# What is the name of this type of series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is the name of a sequence in which each term is r^s where r is some constant and s is variable changing exponentially? How would one sum up such a thing?

An example would be:

1 + (1/2)+ (1/2)^2 + (1/2)^4 + (1/2)^8 + ...

Comment: A variable changing geometrically, huh?

Comment: Yeah, it's kind of a geometric series, but it doesn't sum well.

Comment: So in your example you want to look at the series $\Sigma 2^{-2^n}$?  Do you mean series where $s$ increases exponentially?

Comment: @AlexanderGruber Yep, pretty much. I'm still learning about this stuff, sorry if it's not too complicated.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber Oh whoops. let me change it in my question. thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Power series such as $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^{2^k}$$ which have exponentially large gaps between the powers of successive terms are called [lacunary functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lacunary_function).  I don't think there is any closed-form expression for such a series.  My understanding is that they have very strange behavior as $|z| \rightarrow 1$ for complex numbers $z$.

Answer (score -1):

A series whose terms have a constant ratio (as you seem to describe) is called a $\it{\text{geometric series}}$ and

$$
\sum_{k=1}^n x^n=\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}.
$$

Comment: I know about those, but I'm talking about something slightly different (I think). Only the exponent changes geometrically, not the base or anything.